# How to get all console messages with puppeteer? including errors, CSP violations, failed resources, etc

Tags: puppeteer

I am fetching a page with puppeteer that has some errors in the browser console but the puppeteer's console event is not being triggered by all of the console messages.

The puppeteer chromium browser shows multiple console messages

[image: multiple console messages]

However, puppeteer only console logs one thing in node

[image: console logs one thing in node]

Here is the script I am currently using:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  page.on('console', msg => console.log('PAGE LOG:', msg.text));
  await page.goto('https://pagewithsomeconsoleerrors.com');
  await browser.close();
})();
```

Edit: As stated in my comment below, I did try the page.waitFor(5000) command that Everettss recommended but that didn't work.

Edit2: removed spread operator from `msg.text` as it was there by accident.

Edit3: I opened an issue on github regarding this with similar but different example screenshots: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/1512

Comment: If this errors appears later in runtime try some timeout before `await browser.close();` like this: `await page.waitFor(5000);`

Comment: I tried using page.waitFor but that did not help =/

Comment: @CarlosESilva I am in the same boat. Based on the GitHub issue, you got it working but I still can't make it work. Care to answer your own question here with a sample code along with the version of puppeteer and node you have in use? Thanks!

Comment: did you ever get this working?

Answer (score 96):

The [GitHub issue about capturing console erorrs](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/1512) includes a [great comment about listening to console and network events](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/1512#issuecomment-349784408). For example, you can register for console output and network responses and failures like this:

```js
  page
    .on('console', message =>
      console.log(`${message.type().substr(0, 3).toUpperCase()} ${message.text()}`))
    .on('pageerror', ({ message }) => console.log(message))
    .on('response', response =>
      console.log(`${response.status()} ${response.url()}`))
    .on('requestfailed', request =>
      console.log(`${request.failure().errorText} ${request.url()}`))
```

And get the following output, for example:

```
200 'http://do.carlosesilva.com/puppeteer/'
LOG This is a standard console.log message
Error: This is an error we are forcibly throwing
    at http://do.carlosesilva.com/puppeteer/:22:11
net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED https://do.carlosesilva.com/http-only/sample.png
404 'http://do.carlosesilva.com/puppeteer/this-image-does-not-exist.png'
ERR Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

See also [types of console messages](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v2.0.0/docs/api.md#class-consolemessage) received with the [`console` event](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v2.0.0/docs/api.md#event-console) and [`response`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v2.0.0/docs/api.md#class-response), [`request`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v2.0.0/docs/api.md#class-request) and [`failure`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v2.0.0/docs/api.md#requestfailure) objects received with other events.

If you want to pimp your output with some colours, you can add [chalk, kleur, colorette or others](https://github.com/jorgebucaran/colorette#benchmarks):

```js
  const { blue, cyan, green, magenta, red, yellow } = require('colorette')
  page
    .on('console', message => {
      const type = message.type().substr(0, 3).toUpperCase()
      const colors = {
        LOG: text => text,
        ERR: red,
        WAR: yellow,
        INF: cyan
      }
      const color = colors[type] || blue
      console.log(color(`${type} ${message.text()}`))
    })
    .on('pageerror', ({ message }) => console.log(red(message)))
    .on('response', response =>
      console.log(green(`${response.status()} ${response.url()}`)))
    .on('requestfailed', request =>
      console.log(magenta(`${request.failure().errorText} ${request.url()}`)))
```

The examples above use [Puppeteer API v2.0.0](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v2.0.0/docs/api.md#).

Comment: Seems 'pagerror' gives a useless string type message, like 'OBJECT' in my case. I found a more useable solution `page.on("pageerror", function(err) {  
    theTempValue = err.toString();
    console.log("Page error: " + theTempValue); 
} `

Comment: The [documentation for `pageerror`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v2.0.0/docs/api.md#event-pageerror) specifies an `Error` object, which is supposed to include a `message`. If some errors do not contain a proper message, then the `toString` may help. But it includes the call stack too.

Answer (score 34):

Easiest way to capture all console messages is passing the `dumpio` argument to `puppeteer.launch()`.

From [Puppeteer API docs](https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.launchoptions):

> `dumpio`: <boolean> Whether to pipe the browser process stdout and stderr
> into `process.stdout` and `process.stderr`. Defaults to `false`.

Example code:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
         dumpio: true
    });

    ...

})();
```

Comment: I couldn't see browser console in process stdout, also seems like doc link is broken.

Comment: Fixed the broken link, thanks! Which version are you using? Docs still mention the dumpio argument, but I haven't test with last version.

Comment: I used version 2.0.0. Maybe it's me doing something wrong, will check again later. Thanks!

Comment: "dumpio" seems to show messages outputted by Chrome itself. What appears in console, is not forwarded to stdio.

Answer (score 16):

You need to set multiple listeners if you want to catch everything. The `console` event is emitted when javascript within the page calls a console API message (like `console.log`).

For a full list of the console API take a look at the docs for console on MDN:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console

The reason you need multiple listeners is because some of what is being logged in the image you posted is not happening within the **page**.

So for example, to catch the first error in the image, `net:: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` you would set the listener like so: 
`page.on('requestfailed', err => console.log(err));`

Puppeteer's documentation contains a full list of events. You should take a look at the documentation for the version you are using and look at the different events the Page class will emit as well as what those events will return. The example I've written above will return an instance of Puppeteer's request class.

https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#class-page

Answer (score 1):

I extended **Ferdinand**'s great comment code with descriptive errors text from `JSHandle` `consoleMessage` object in next comment. So you can catch all the errors from the browser and read all the description like in browser console.

Check it out there https://stackoverflow.com/a/66801550/9026103