# puppeteer how to find page errors

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

[Source](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#event-pageerror)

*How do I capture page errors?? 
I was trying to find page errors using puppeteer.
its not showing anything*

> Here code I used

```
 const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

    (async () => {
      const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false
      });
      const page = await browser.newPage();

      // Open page.
      await page.goto('http://example.com/');

        page.on('error', (err) => {
        console.log('error: ', err)
      })
      page.on('pageerror', (err) => {
        console.log('pageerror: ', err)
      })
      page.on('console', msg => {
        for (let i = 0; i < msg.args.length; ++i)
          console.log(`${i}: ${msg.args[i]}`)
      })

      // Keep the browser open.
      // browser.close();
    })();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get all console messages with puppeteer? including errors, CSP violations, failed resources, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47539043/how-to-get-all-console-messages-with-puppeteer-including-errors-csp-violations)

Answer (score 2):

Also, add this listener:

```js
page.on('requestfailed', console.error.bind(console, 'REQUEST_FAILED:\n')
```

Maybe help you.