# How to execute a js function on the page while automating in puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

Say the script has navigated to a certain page. How to execute a js function inside that script?

```
describe("TestSuite", () => {
  test("Login", async() => {
    await page.goto(APP);
    await page.waitForSelector("[name=loginForm]");
    await page.click("input[name=username]");
    await page.type("input[name=username]", user.username);
    await page.click("input[name=pwd]");
    await page.type("input[name=pwd]", user.pwd);
    await page.click("input[name=login]");
    await page.waitForSelector(".PageBodyVertical");

 // execute a js function x() here which is loaded with the page.

  }, 60000);
```

Comment: Add a click event that calls  that function to a button then use
`page.click('that_button')`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use the .evaluate() function.

```
describe("TestSuite", () => {
  test("Login", async() => {
    await page.goto(APP);
    await page.waitForSelector("[name=loginForm]");
    await page.click("input[name=username]");
    await page.type("input[name=username]", user.username);
    await page.click("input[name=pwd]");
    await page.type("input[name=pwd]", user.pwd);
    await page.click("input[name=login]");
    await page.waitForSelector(".PageBodyVertical");

    await page.evaluate( function(){
      x();
    } );

  }, 60000);
```

Comment: How do you pass a variable into that javascript?

Comment: @CodeGuru by searching on stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/a/46098448/5036031

Comment: await page.evaluate(() => fLogon()); getting undefined flogon on typecript

Comment: Create fake function from resolve error type script:
Ex:
function x() {
   return 'Fake func'
}

Answer (score 3):

Example with args:

```
let a1 = "hello";
let a2 = " world";

const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.evaluate(function(a1, a2){
      console.log('msg: ' + a1 + a2); // This code runs in the page's context and returns the result
}, a1, a2);
```

Puppeteer evaluate docs: https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.page.evaluate

Note 1: In order to see the console print you need to [add a listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47539043/how-to-get-all-console-messages-with-puppeteer-including-errors-csp-violations)

Note 2: In order to invoke your own functions within `evaluate` you need to [expose the function](https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.page.exposefunction/)